# AngularUI unable to change state with ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have the following simple navigation:

```
<ul class="iconsLine ic2 etabs">
    <li>
        <a ui-sref="dashboard.tree.workstation.queue"><span class="icos-user"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a ui-sref="dashboard.tree.workstation.settings"><span class="icos-cog2"></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div ui-view="detailDialogContent"></div>
```

These links do not change the state.  However, if I execute `$state.transitionTo("dashboard.tree.workstation.settings");` everything will show as I would expect it to when I click the link.

I don't see anything I'm missing here.  Am I crazy?

**State definition:**

```
        state('dashboard.tree.workstation.settings', {
            onEnter: function () {
                console.log('dashboard.tree.workstation.settings');
            },
            views: {
                'detailDialogContent': {
                    templateUrl: '/partials/admin/dialog/bits/workstation-settings.htm'
                }
            }
        }).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out v0.0.1 does not have this directive.  So I went and grabbed it from https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/stateDirectives.js and included it in my project.